# Record retropie on TwisterOS

Tags: retropie, screen-recorder

Hello I have a raspberry pi 4 8gb with TwisterOS 2.1.2, which includes retropie in the 4.8.4 version

I tried various screens recorders as "Simple screen recorder", "Vokoscreen" and "Kazam" and all these works but when I open retropie only records a black screen with the cursor.

Comment: As far as I know, Retropie may be blocking screen recorders from recording it. It is kinda like how you cannot record some streaming platforms like Netflix because it shows as black. Hope this info helps somehow.